# attempt to write a readonly database in android

Tags: android, database

When attempting to update value, these error are occuring,

```
02-09 11:37:53.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4809): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: attempt to write a readonly database: UPDATE studnet SET isMarried=1  WHERE _id = 40
```

my database file

**...data/data/a.b.c/test.sql**

and my query in DBHelper.java

```
public void checkMarried(int checkPoint) {
    String Query = "UPDATE student SET ismarried=1  WHERE _id = " + checkPoint ;
    DB.execSQL(Query);
}
```

Executing code is

```
String iNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
int checkNumber=Integer.parseInt(iNumber);
db.bookmarkedJok(checkNumber);
```

where db is object of   DatabaseHelper .

How to change permission of database file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use **getWritableDatabase()** before executing your query in your checkMarried() method

```
 public void checkMarried(int checkPoint) {

        DB=this.getWritableDatabase() ;
        String Query = "UPDATE student SET ismarried=1  WHERE _id = " + checkPoint ;
        DB.execSQL(Query);

      }
```

Hope it will work now.

Comment: you should accept the answer if you think it was helpful to you