# Attempting to write in a readonly database Titanium Android

Tags: android, sqlite, titanium

I have opened the db file from my sdcard. And i need to update in that file itself when changes occurs.

```
if (Ti.Platform.name === 'android' && Ti.Filesystem.isExternalStoragePresent()) {
var db2 = Ti.Database.open(Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory + 'path' + Ti.Filesystem.separator + 'to' + Ti.Filesystem.separator + 'mydb2Installed'); }
```

When i tried to update ., it says

> "ReadOnly file cannot be updated"

I want to make this as a writable database file. In native android i have a solution,

```
this.getWritableDatabase() ;
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206187/attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database-in-android)

in Titanium how can i make this is as writable file ??

NOTE: In TiApp.xml, I added permission for

> WRITE_EXTERNALSTORAGE

Comment: do you have a Primary key in your table?

Comment: @Dragon: yes, Primary key exists.